# Elements are not created in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Achievement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int total_money;
    public int money;

    bool isFirst;

    public string[] arrayTitles;
    public Sprite[] arraySprite;
    public GameObject button;
    public GameObject content;
    
    private List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();
    private VerticalLayoutGroup _group;

    void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        total_money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        isFirst = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirst") == 1 ? true : false;

        RectTransform recT = content.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        recT.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        _group = GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>();
        setAchievs();
    }

    private void RemovedList()
    {
        foreach (var elem in list)
        {
            Destroy(elem);
        }

        list.Clear();
    }

    void setAchievs()
    {
        RectTransform recT = content.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        recT.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        RemovedList();

        if (arrayTitles.Length > 0)
        {
            var pr1 = Instantiate(button, transform);
            var h = pr1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
            var tr = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            tr.sizeDelta = new Vector2(tr.rect.width, h * arrayTitles.Length);
            Destroy(pr1);

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayTitles.Length; i++)
            {
                var pr = Instantiate(button, transform);
                pr.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = arrayTitles[i];
                pr.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].sprite = arraySprite[i];
                var i1 = i;
                pr.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => GetAchievement(i1));
                list.Add(pr);
            }
        }
    }

    void GetAchievement(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case 0:
                break;

            case 1:
                money += 100;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
                break;

            case 2:
                money += 1000;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Tomenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
  
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

New buttons are not being created in unity, they are not being created. 1 case is created and that's it.

Initially, I manually created a new achievement, but then I decided that it would be easier and shorter to do it through cases, but something went wrong and achievements are not created

[image: en]

[image: enter im]

[image: enter image description]

[image: here]

[image: age description here]

[image: ter image description here]